# start activity inside another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, inner-classes

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class GoogleDriveSync extends AppCompatActivity {

     // What Happens When App Is Resumed//
     @Override
     protected void onStart() {

         // Where I Want To Start Inner Class//

         super.onStart();
     }

     private class SyncReminders extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

         @Override
         public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

     }
}
```

Inside that Class I have another class. The main class will eventually have three private classes in it. How do I start the inner class using an intent. Thanks!

Comment: Why is `SyncReminders` an inner class? What are your reasons for doing this? Also, why do you want to start it immediately after `GoogleDriveSync` starts? Why not just start `SyncReminders` directly?

Comment: Perhaps `SyncReminders` should be a `Service` instead of an `Activity`?

Comment: I only put one there but I need three seperate Sync classes in the main GoogleSriveSync class. I dont want to make three seperate classes if i dont have too. It would be nice to have the three classes inside the big class. I would like to start one of them directly then the rest after the first one finishes

Answer (score 1):

It would have to be a `public static` subclass of `Activity` (or `AppCompatActivity`, as you have it here), not a `private` class. You would then start it via `startActivity()`, the same way that you start up any other activity.

However, it is unclear why you are doing any of this. Starting an activity from `onStart()` of another activity is unlikely to be want you want.

Let's walk through what will happen, assuming that your strangely-named `GoogleDriveSync` activity is the launcher activity:

- User taps your launcher icon
- Android creates an instance of `GoogleDriveSync`
- Android calls `onCreate()` on your `GoogleDriveSync` instance
- Android calls `onStart()` on your `GoogleDriveSync`, where you call `startActivity()` to start `SyncReminders`
- Android calls `onStop()` on your `GoogleDriveSync`, as it will no longer be visible (assuming that `SyncReminders` is a typical activity, filling the screen)
- Android creates an instance of `SyncReminders`, goes through its lifecycle methods, and shows it
- Eventually, the user tries pressing BACK
- Android calls `onStart()` on your `GoogleDriveSync`, where you call `startActivity()` to start `SyncReminders`
- Android calls `onStop()` on your `GoogleDriveSync`, as it will no longer be visible (assuming that `SyncReminders` is a typical activity, filling the screen)
- Android creates an instance of `SyncReminders`, goes through its lifecycle methods, and shows it
- Eventually, the user tries pressing BACK
- Android calls `onStart()` on your `GoogleDriveSync`, where you call `startActivity()` to start `SyncReminders`

And so on.

In other words, the UI of `GoogleDriveSync` will never be shown, and the user will wonder why she cannot exit `SyncReminders`.

Unless there is a **clear reason** for using two activities here, use just one activity.

Comment: I need three separate classes one for syncing my reminders, one for syncing my events, and one for syncing my users. I can't do it all in one class because things conflict but I dont want to make three sepeate classes because that seems stupid to me because I feel like they should all go together. Thats why I was hoping I could make one class and have all three of the seperate classes in that class that way they are all togther but dont seporate from one another. I dont want any visual going with this. I want it to happen onyl when the user opens the app.

Comment: @Jordan: "I dont want any visual going with this" -- then you should not be creating activities, which are visual by nature.